# How to give cloudfront or any resource access to another account role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-iam, aws-sts

I have a cloudfront, let's say in Account A and I want to access this cloudfront from a  build server which is in another AWS account let's say in Account B with IAM Role.

How to give a IAM role access(Account B) to that cloudfront which is in Account A.

Note: Please consider Role not IAM user.

Comment: what is the end task once you get the access to cloudfront from different account ?

Answer (score 0):

[Overview of Managing Access Permissions to Your CloudFront Resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/access-control-overview.html)

> An AWS account owns the resources that are created in the account,
>   regardless of who created the resources. Specifically, the resource
>   owner is the AWS account of the principal entity (that is, the root
>   account, an IAM user, or an IAM role) that authenticates the resource
>   creation request.
>
> The following examples illustrate how this works:
>
> - > Attach a permissions policy to a role (grant cross-account
>   >     permissions) – You can grant permissions to perform CloudFront actions
>   >     to a user that was created in another AWS account. To do so, you
>   >     attach a permissions policy to an IAM role, and then you allow the
>   >     user in the other account to assume the role. The following example
>   >     explains how this works for two AWS accounts, account A and account B:
> - > Account A administrator creates an IAM role and attaches to the role a
>   >     permissions policy that grants permissions to create or access
>   >     resources that are owned by account A.
> - > Account A administrator attaches a trust policy to the role. The trust
>   >     policy identifies account B as the principal that can assume the role.
> - > Account B administrator can then delegate permissions to assume the
>   >     role to users or groups in account B. This allows users in account B
>   >     to create or access resources in account A.
>   >     For more information about how to delegate permissions to users in
>   >     another AWS account, see Access Management in the IAM User Guide.